# Which statistical test to determine interaction effect?

Tags: interaction, multiple-comparisons, paired-data

I conducted an experiment to determine the effect of blood type on blood cell interactions with proteins of differing blood groups and want to determine if there is an interaction effect for the continuous variables that I measured.

I have 3 of blood type A and 7 of type O. These samples were analysed on surfaces coated with protein of mixed blood type, type A, and type O. I have raw data and also data normalized to each individual patient to account for inter-individual differences in the samples.

What statistical test can I use to analyse these data and determine if there is an interaction effect?

I have access to SPSS and know how to run some basic statistics in Python. If you can advise me on how to implement the statistical test in either of these software, that would be massively appreciated.